# UIView custom transition snaps back on completion

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, transition, caanimation

I have implemented a class `BubbleAnimator`, that should create a bubble-like transition between views and added it through the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`-protocol. The presenting animation works fine so far (that's why I haven't added all the code for this part).

But on dismissing the view, the 'fromViewController' **flashes up** at the very end of the animation. After this very short flash, the correct `toViewController` is displayed again, but this glitch is very annoying.
The following is the relevant `animateTransition`-method:

```
    //Get all the necessary views from the context
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)

    //Presenting
    if self.reverse == false {

        //Add the destinationvc as subview
        containerView!.addSubview(fromViewController!.view)
        containerView!.addSubview(toViewController!.view)

        /*...Animating the layer goes here... */

    //Dismissing
    } else {
        containerView!.addSubview(toViewController!.view)
        containerView!.addSubview(fromViewController!.view)

        //Init the paths
        let circleMaskPathInitial = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: self.originFrame)
        let extremePoint = CGPoint(x: originFrame.origin.x , y: originFrame.origin.y - CGRectGetHeight(toViewController!.view.bounds) )
        let radius = sqrt((extremePoint.x*extremePoint.x) + (extremePoint.y*extremePoint.y))
        let circleMaskPathFinal = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectInset(originFrame, -radius, -radius))

        //Create a layer
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = circleMaskPathFinal.CGPath
        fromViewController!.view.layer.mask = maskLayer


        //Create and add the animation
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.toValue = circleMaskPathInitial.CGPath
        animation.fromValue = circleMaskPathFinal.CGPath
        animation.duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)
        animation.delegate = self
        maskLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "path")
    }
```

The cleanup takes place in the delegate method:

```
override public func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    self.transitionContext?.completeTransition(!(self.transitionContext?.transitionWasCancelled())!)
}
```

I guess, that I am doing something wrong with adding the views to the containerView, but I couldn't figure it out. Another possibility is, that the view's layer mask gets reset, when the function `completeTransition` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this blogpost](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/11/prevent-caanimation-snap-back/) I have finally been able to solve this problem. Short explanation:

The CAAnimation only manipulates the presentation-layer of the view, but does not change the model-layer. When the animation now finishes, it's value snaps back to the original and unchanged value of the model-layer.

Short and simply workaround:

```
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.removedOnCompletion = false
```

The better solution, as it doesn't prevent the animation from being removed is to manually set the final value of the layer's position before the animation starts. This way, the model-layer is assigned the correct value:

```
        maskLayer.path = circleMaskPathInitial.CGPath
        //Create and add the animation below..
```